# Openswan ip tunnel not passing traffic

Tags: openswan

I had this tunnel already working, but now I needed to add two more ips 10.50.240.48/28  and 10.50.96.0/20. I set up my left and right and leftsubnets and rightsubnets properly in the openswan config. It has already been working but I just added two more segments:

```
leftsubnets=    {10.122.91.0/24 10.153.136.0/24 10.50.240.48/28 10.50.96.0/20 10.37.200.0/24 10.53.221.0/24}
```

Then since my shorewall firewall was already configured to accept traffic from this tunnel, I just needed to add the two broadcasts for the two added ip addresses in /etc/shorewall/interfaces:

```
#ZONE   INTERFACE   BROADCAST   OPTIONS
...
vpn2    tun2        10.122.91.255,10.153.139.255,10.50.240.63,10.50.111.255,10.37.200.255,10.53.221.255
```

Here's some output from ipsec auto --status:

```
000 #993: "wyless/1x0" esp.b24e9031@74.205.127.225 esp.c50b26e3@myip tun.0@74.205.127.225 tun.0@myip ref=0 refhim=4294901761
000 #977: "wyless/1x0":500 STATE_MAIN_R3 (sent MR3, ISAKMP SA established); EVENT_SA_REPLACE in 1618s; newest ISAKMP; lastdpd=59s(seq in:0 out:0); idle; import:admin initiate
000 #994: "wyless/2x0":500 STATE_QUICK_I2 (sent QI2, IPsec SA established); EVENT_SA_REPLACE in 27432s; newest IPSEC; eroute owner; isakmp#977; idle; import:admin initiate
000 #994: "wyless/2x0" esp.7fc2b25f@74.205.127.225 esp.30d47987@myip tun.0@74.205.127.225 tun.0@myip ref=0 refhim=4294901761
000 #995: "wyless/3x0":500 STATE_QUICK_I2 (sent QI2, IPsec SA established); EVENT_SA_REPLACE in 26959s; newest IPSEC; eroute owner; isakmp#977; idle; import:admin initiate
000 #995: "wyless/3x0" esp.71d4fe4d@74.205.127.225 esp.1b465e60@myip tun.0@74.205.127.225 tun.0@myip ref=0 refhim=4294901761
000 #551: "wyless/4x0":500 STATE_QUICK_R2 (IPsec SA established); EVENT_SA_REPLACE in 5719s; newest IPSEC; eroute owner; isakmp#542; idle; import:not set
000 #551: "wyless/4x0" esp.baef82ef@74.205.127.225 esp.5b253e7a@myip tun.0@74.205.127.225 tun.0@myip ref=0 refhim=4294901761
000 #996: "wyless/5x0":500 STATE_QUICK_I2 (sent QI2, IPsec SA established); EVENT_SA_REPLACE in 27444s; newest IPSEC; eroute owner; isakmp#977; idle; import:admin initiate
000 #996: "wyless/5x0" esp.606de7ab@74.205.127.225 esp.ceb8c9d5@myip tun.0@74.205.127.225 tun.0@myip ref=0 refhim=4294901761
000 #559: "wyless/6x0":500 STATE_QUICK_I2 (sent QI2, IPsec SA established); EVENT_SA_REPLACE in 5076s; newest IPSEC; eroute owner; isakmp#542; idle; import:admin initiate
000 #559: "wyless/6x0" esp.e4694bcf@74.205.127.225 esp.3b11db56@myip tun.0@74.205.127.225 tun.0@myip ref=0 refhim=4294901761
000
```

Any idea how I can troubleshoot this further?

Comment: Check your routing table with the route -n command. Use tracert to troubleshoot the routes.